# UI-Router abstract state infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am transitioning from ngroute and am trying to add an abstract state to my routes that provides authentication checking. If the user is not authenticated, then redirect them to `/login` if they are authenticated, continue.

One key point is that if the user tries to go to `/login` while they are authenticated, it will redirect them to `/`.

The issue I am having is if the user is not authenticated and they are redirected to `/login` the abstract parent state is triggered and checks if they are authenticated, and redirects them to login...etc in an infinite loop.

```
angular.module('qaApp').factory('authorization', ['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'userService', 
    function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, userService){
        return {
            authorize: function(){
                return userService.identity().then(
                    function(){
                        let isAuthenticated = userService.isAuthenticated;
                        if(!isAuthenticated){
                            $state.is('login'); //Always false
                            $state.includes('login'); //Always false

                            //Somehow check to ensure next route is not /login
                            $state.go('login');
                        }
                        //Else if next route is /login redirect to /home...etc
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }]);


angular.module('qaApp').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    $stateProvider.state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        resolve: {
            authorize: ['authorization', function(authorization){
                return authorization.authorize();
            }]
        }
    })
    .state('login', {
        parent: 'app',
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController',
        controllerAs: 'login'
    })
})
```

How can I ensure that the `$state.go('login')` only occurs when the next route is NOT `/login`?

Answer (score 0):

state "login" is child state of "app".
1. request to move to "/login" then
2. router catch the request and check it is authorized.
3. if request is not authorized, router will redirect request to "/login".
Then go back to 1.
so, infinite request to "/login" is occurred.

So, don't put "login" state under "app" state.
I think you can divide states like this.
(make login state don't need to be authorized.)
.app
..login
..abstractStateToAuthorize
...anotherStatesAfterAuthorization